# How can I get the difference in days using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, date

I need to print the difference (in days) for ($6) between the starting and end date of records for each unique ID ($5) which have more than two records on a new field.

the data looks like this

```
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30    
7  82  2    10  41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45   
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-03-25    10:15:45  
7  83  1    67  29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25          
7  81  1    47  32070  2011-5-11     08:14:20  
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-03-10    06:10:23  
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-02-28    06:25:30    
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24  
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30   147    
7  82  2    10  41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45   150  
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-03-25    10:15:45   147  
7  83  1    67  29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25   189       
7  81  1    47  32070  2011-5-11     08:14:20   147  
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-03-10    06:10:23   189  
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-02-28    06:25:30   150   
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24   189  
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25   150
```

I wrote the following code but it doesn't take in to account for more than two record for each unique ID ($5).

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {  
           c = "date -d \""$6 "\" +%s"; # use system date for epoch time seconds  
           c | getline d;                 # execute command in c var,output to d   
           a[$5] = (($5 in a) ? d-a[$5] : d); # set or subtract from array  
           next                           # skip to next record  
       } {                                # for the second go:  
           # $1=$1;                       # uncomment to clean trailing space  
           print $0, int(a[$5]/86400)     # print record and time  difference  
       }' file file
```

Comment: This is a pretty standard question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried but it only take in to account for two record for each ID. however, my data set has more than two records and gave me unexpected result. How should the dates be handled if there are more than 2 records for each id?

Comment: You are supposed to show us some code, to convice us that we will not be doing your homework for you.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs see my edit.

Comment: Are you using `GNU awk`, which contains a number of useful time functions?

Comment: yes I'm using GNU awk.

Comment: Related: [How to use awk command to calculate the date difference between two columns in the same file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330766/how-to-use-awk-command-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-two-columns-in-t/330773#330773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires `GNU awk`:

```
NR == FNR {
    split($6, arr, "-");
    date = mktime(sprintf("%4d %02d %02d 00 00 00", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]));
    if (!start[$5] || date < start[$5]) {
        start[$5] = date;
    }
    if (date > stop[$5]) {
        stop[$5] = date;
    }
    next;
}

{
    print $0 " " int((stop[$5] - start[$5]) / (3600 * 24));
}
```

Comment: @Alula if this answer works for you please accept it with the tick mark on the left. This is how StackExchange sites work